# Is there a possible way to access the first 3 <img> inside the content of an iframe using javascript jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, iframe

I want to access the first 3  inside the content of my iFrame to adjust its width because it is too big for the my iFrame, and it has been said that the iFrame width cannot be changed.

I already have the code

```
iFrame.contents().find("img").first().width(300);
```

and it changed the first  in the content, I have tried using

```
iFrame.contents().find("img").next().width(300);
```

but it doesn't work, are there any approach for this?

ps. I don't have any access to the html file that I am outputting in my iFrame.

Comment: what is this `iFrame` variable? -perhaps `[...iFrame.contents().find("img")].slice(0,3).forEach(v => $(v).width(300))` - or maybe that last bit can be `.forEach(v => v.width(300))` - I forget how jquery works by not using it for 10 years

Comment: Important question: is the `src` of your iframe on the same domain and can you access it? Not even jQuery can cheat you into looking at a different sites page.

Comment: @somethinghere since the first code `changed the first in the content`, I'd say yours is a moot (yet valid) point :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Ah yes. Oops.

Comment: @somethinghere still a valid point for other scenarios

Comment: @JaromandaX Hey, thanks it worked, I changed the code to iFrame.contents().find("img").slice(0,3).width(300);

Comment: I guess that works too ... didn't think jQuery has a .slice, but it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery::slice() to get the first 3 images:

```
iFrame.contents().find("img").slice(0, 3).width(300);
```

https://api.jquery.com/slice/